# What is the appropriate coredns config using calico?

Tags: kubernetes, coredns, calico

None of the pods resolve public domains or any internal pods. The resolv.conf points to an ip that doesn't belong to coredns

```
IP of coredns: 192.168.208.7
```

```
#cat etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local ec2.internal
options ndots:5
```

What should i change to fix this dns issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several steps you should take when [Debugging DNS Resolution](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/):

> This page provides hints on diagnosing DNS problems.

Try in that order:

- [Check the local DNS configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#check-the-local-dns-configuration-first)
- [Check if the DNS pod is running](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#check-if-the-dns-pod-is-running)
- [Check for errors in the DNS pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#check-for-errors-in-the-dns-pod)
- [Check if DNS service is up](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#is-dns-service-up)
- [Are DNS endpoints exposed?](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#are-dns-endpoints-exposed)
- [Are DNS queries being received/processed?](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#are-dns-queries-being-received-processed)
- and the [Known issues](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#known-issues)

Sometimes it's just the matter of restarting the coredns deployment:

```
kubectl -n kube-system rollout restart deployment coredns
```

Also, there is always an option to [install](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/coredns/) it fresh.

Comment: Damn, the reboot fixed the issue, took me three weeks to try it... My setup was kube + calico if it can help anyone else.